# To group by name and rank by appearance and add count while eliminating names not associated in top 2 within each state(descending)?

Tags: r, list, count, rank

For example I have a dataset that looks like this

```
    name |  state
   Smith      NY
 Anthony      CA
   James      MA
   Henry      CA
 Andrews      NY
   Helen      CA
   Smith      NY
   Smith      NY
 Anthony      CA
 Andrews      NY
 Richard      MA
 Richard      MA
 Richard      MA
 Anthony      CA
  Smith       MA
 Jeffries     CA
 Conrad       NY
  Hanes       NY
  James       MA
  Conrad      NY
  Conrad      NY
  Helen       CA
```

In the end i would like something like this. Note that states is ordered alphabetically. Note that the names with most appearance show at the top and the one with next appearance follows after. I only select the top two in each grouping(state) then i create those columns reference their rank and count based on row apperances.

```
  name|   state| Rank | Count 
Anthony     CA     1        3
Anthony     CA     1        3
Anthony     CA     1        3
 Helen      CA     2        2
 Helen      CA     2        2
Richard     MA     1        3
Richard     MA     1        3
Richard     MA     1        3
  James     MA     2        2
  James     MA     2        2
Smith       NY     1        3
Smith       NY     1        3
Smith       NY     1        3
Conrad      NY     1        3
Conrad      NY     1        3
Conrad      NY     1        3
```

Comment: by the number of appearances for row within a state. Anthony for California is 1 and Helen is 2 because Anthony shows up in the raw dataset in three rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   add_count(name, state) %>% 
   group_by(state) %>%
   mutate(Rank = dense_rank(-n)) %>% 
   arrange(state, Rank) %>% 
   filter(Rank %in% 1:2)
# A tibble: 18 x 4
# Groups:   state [3]
   name    state     n  Rank
   <chr>   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 Anthony CA        3     1
 2 Anthony CA        3     1
 3 Anthony CA        3     1
 4 Helen   CA        2     2
 5 Helen   CA        2     2
 6 Richard MA        3     1
 7 Richard MA        3     1
 8 Richard MA        3     1
 9 James   MA        2     2
10 James   MA        2     2
11 Smith   NY        3     1
12 Smith   NY        3     1
13 Smith   NY        3     1
14 Conrad  NY        3     1
15 Conrad  NY        3     1
16 Conrad  NY        3     1
17 Andrews NY        2     2
18 Andrews NY        2     2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("Smith", "Anthony", "James", "Henry", 
"Andrews", "Helen", "Smith", "Smith", "Anthony", "Andrews", "Richard", 
"Richard", "Richard", "Anthony", "Smith", "Jeffries", "Conrad", 
"Hanes", "James", "Conrad", "Conrad", "Helen"), state = c("NY", 
"CA", "MA", "CA", "NY", "CA", "NY", "NY", "CA", "NY", "MA", "MA", 
"MA", "CA", "MA", "CA", "NY", "NY", "MA", "NY", "NY", "CA")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```